# {{ }} operator not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to print the variable **name** it prints **{{name}}** and not as a variable, I don't know where I am going wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyTestApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> src = "app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divx" ng-controller="MyTestController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
                <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('MyTestApp', [])

.controller('MyTestController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Angular";
  $scope.sayHello = function () {
    return "From function";
  };
});

})();
```

Comment: You aren't defining your script tags properly. If you hit f12 and look at console you should see that angular is not a function error. `<script src='angular.min.js'></script>` Also Inputs are self closing tags. You should review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input on how to properly use them

Comment: As @scrappedcola mentioned, correct your script tags. There is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: I did long back, The edit isn't updated

Comment: **<script type="text/javascript"> src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"> </script>**
is my current script tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues,

(i) The scripts should be refereed as

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"> </script>
```

(ii) You should not place **`{{name}}`** inside a input element. change it inside a **`<h1>`** or **`<p>`** tag as follows.

**DEMO**

```js
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('MyTestApp', [])

.controller('MyTestController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Angular";
  $scope.sayHello = function () {
    return "From function";
  };
});

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyTestApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divx" ng-controller="MyTestController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <h1> {{name}}</h1>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the changes that you mentioned but I still get the same error.

Comment: properly check the mentioned changes, did you check the script? look at the demo

Comment: I edited the changes even in my question, can you check it?

Comment: still look at your references, they are wrong it should be as mentioned in the answer

Comment: I don't understand what change are you mentioning about, I am not seeing any change can you specify it.

Comment: dude!  <script type="text/javascript"> src = "app.js"> </script> should be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161343/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-rahul).